# Возврат результата после асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript, ajax, ооп

Получаю после вызова функции __self.getJSonData() - **пустой обьект {}**.
Может кто-то найдет ошибку/проблему.

Вот код

```js
(function() {

  function Calculator() {

    var __self = this;

    this.render = function() {
      console.log(__self.getJSonData());
    }

  }


  //Получить данные из JSON
  Calculator.prototype.getJSonData = function() {
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = 'data.json';
      var self = this;
      var data = {};


      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
          returnData(ajax.responseText);
        }
      };

      ajax.open("GET", url, true);
      ajax.send();



      function returnData(json) {
        data = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(data);
      }

      return data;
  };




  window.calculator = new Calculator();
  calculator.render();

})();
```

Comment: `getJSonData` возвращается гораздо раньше, чем срабатывает асинхронный `ajax.onreadystatechange`, внутри которого Вы присваиваете `data` непустое значение

Comment: а можно как то это реализовать по другому ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {

  function Calculator() {
    this.render = this.getJSonData(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
  }


  //Получить данные из JSON
  Calculator.prototype.getJSonData = function(callback) {
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = 'data.json';
      var self = this;
      var data = {};


      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
          returnData(ajax.responseText);
        }
      };

      ajax.open("GET", url, true);
      ajax.send();



      function returnData(json) {
        data = JSON.parse(json);
        if (callback) {
            callback(data)
        }
      }
  };




  window.calculator = new Calculator();
  calculator.render();

})();
```